# Flutter: Is there a way to prevent Marker scaling with zooming in and out? And reposition them to absolute center of image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Markers to place images in a Google Map. Issue#1: The very bottom of my marker image is always the latitude and longitude of where I'm placing the image. The top and center are not. For example:

[image]

Those markers are generated based on my location and they are showing above my actual location. Is there any way to make my latitude and longitude entries the absolute center of my marker images?

#2: How can I prevent markers from remaining the same size as I zoom in and out on my map?

Comment: You should provide more details (some code, which libraries you used to display map, ...)

Comment: It's Google Map Flutter. Basic marker dropping. If you drop a marker ontap or button press, it won't use the markers center as the drop point, it uses the markers very bottom point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Marker` widget's default anchor is `Offset(0.5, 1.0)` hence when you're adding a marker it's bottom center is being placed on the location. You need to change it to this `Offset(0.5, 0.5)`:

```
Marker(
    anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5)
);
```

For your second question I think there is no way unless you rebuild your markers every time the zoom changes and change sizes as you like.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe it was that easy. It works perfectly! Thank you!!! Can I pick your brain a bit? rather than plotting partial circles, I'm drawing on the map using canvas. It's a bit of a headache and I can't get it quite right. Do you think it would be better to pursue some sort of algo involving polylines? Where initial latlng is supplied and results in a distance followed by two points resulting in a cone? This is what I'm pursuing: http://www.earthsurvey.us/rings/rings.html  (The Sector of Disk function)

Comment: I'm not expert in drawing on maps but I don't think it's achievable using polylines so I would go with canvas @tsy